# Create multiple columns using pairs of different columns with map2

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(n_val1 =c(1,2,1,1), n_val2 = c(2,3,5,1), p_val1 = c(2,4,5,1), p_val2 = c(2,3,1,1), n_sum_val1 = c(5,4,2,4), n_sum_val2 = c(6,7,8,9), p_sum_val1 = c(5, 9, 1, 3), p_sum_val2 = c(6,8,2,4) )
```

I want calculate corresponding percentage (e.g., n_val1/n_sum_val1, n_val2/n_sum_val2), same applies to (p_val1/p_sum_val1, p_val2/p_sum_val2). To do this, I used the following code for one pair:

```
map2(c(paste0('n_val', 1:2)), c(paste0('n_sum_val', 1:2)), ~ df[[.x]] / df[[.y]] ) %>% set_names(c(paste0('n_pct', 1:2))) %>% bind_cols(df, .)
```

How can I calculate percentages for both pairs of columns p_ and n_ ?

Answer (score 1):

You have a lot of what I might call metadata encoded in those column names that you want to use to match them. Therefore I suggest using `tidyr::pivot_longer()` to get that metadata out of column names and into the actual `data.frame` and then parse it out so you can match the each record with the sum you want to divide by.

I used `tidyr::unite()` to restore your original column names and  `tidyr::pivot_wider()` to put it back into 'wide' format.

Note on the first `separate()` call I used a `regex` that splits on the **last** occurrence of `_` since some of them have the word `sum` and some don't.

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(n_val1 =c(1,2,1,1), n_val2 = c(2,3,5,1), p_val1 = c(2,4,5,1), p_val2 = c(2,3,1,1), n_sum_val1 = c(5,4,2,4), n_sum_val2 = c(6,7,8,9), p_sum_val1 = c(5, 9, 1, 3), p_sum_val2 = c(6,8,2,4) )

df %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-id) %>% 
  separate(name, into = c("a", "c"), sep = "_(?!(?s:.*)_)") %>% 
  separate(a, into = c("a", "b"), sep = "_") %>% 
  separate(c, into = c("c", "d"), sep = 3) %>% 
  mutate(b = case_when(
    is.na(b) ~ "numerator", 
    T ~ "denominator")) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = b, values_from = value) %>% 
  mutate(percent = numerator/denominator) %>% 
  pivot_longer(numerator:denominator, names_to = "b") %>% 
  mutate(b = case_when(b == "denominator" ~ "sum")) %>% 
  unite("name", c(a, b, c, d), na.rm = T) %>% 
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(value, percent), names_from = name, names_glue = "{name}_{.value}")
#> Warning: Expected 2 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 16 rows [1, 2, 3,
#> 4, 9, 10, 11, 12, 17, 18, 19, 20, 25, 26, 27, 28].
#> # A tibble: 4 x 17
#>      id n_val_1_value n_sum_val_1_value n_val_2_value n_sum_val_2_value
#>   <int>         <dbl>             <dbl>         <dbl>             <dbl>
#> 1     1             1                 5             2                 6
#> 2     2             2                 4             3                 7
#> 3     3             1                 2             5                 8
#> 4     4             1                 4             1                 9
#> # ... with 12 more variables: p_val_1_value <dbl>, p_sum_val_1_value <dbl>,
#> #   p_val_2_value <dbl>, p_sum_val_2_value <dbl>, n_val_1_percent <dbl>,
#> #   n_sum_val_1_percent <dbl>, n_val_2_percent <dbl>,
#> #   n_sum_val_2_percent <dbl>, p_val_1_percent <dbl>,
#> #   p_sum_val_1_percent <dbl>, p_val_2_percent <dbl>, p_sum_val_2_percent <dbl>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I appreciate if you could please output the data in same format as my map2 command above. I tried uniting and pivoting,   `tidyr::unite("z", a:d, remove = FALSE) %>% pivot_wider(names_from = z, values_from = percent)`, but this does not seem to working.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using tidyverse with `across`. You can select the columns based on a character pattern (e.g., starts with "n_val" and "n_sum_val"). Your new column names can be indicated based on the pattern using the .names argument.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(across(starts_with("n_val"), .names = "pct_{col}") / across(starts_with("n_sum_val")),
         across(starts_with("p_val"), .names = "pct_{col}") / across(starts_with("p_sum_val")))
```

**Output**

```
  n_val1 n_val2 p_val1 p_val2 n_sum_val1 n_sum_val2 p_sum_val1 p_sum_val2 pct_n_val1 pct_n_val2 pct_p_val1 pct_p_val2
1      1      2      2      2          5          6          5          6       0.20  0.3333333  0.4000000  0.3333333
2      2      3      4      3          4          7          9          8       0.50  0.4285714  0.4444444  0.3750000
3      1      5      5      1          2          8          1          2       0.50  0.6250000  5.0000000  0.5000000
4      1      1      1      1          4          9          3          4       0.25  0.1111111  0.3333333  0.2500000
```